# Computing accurate values of $f(x) = (x+1)^{1/3} −x^{1/3}$ for $x>0$

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

*Write* a function that computes accurate values of  $$f(x) = (x+1)^{1/3} −x^{1/3}$$ for $x>0$.

Comment: Since you're new here, I'd like to share some things about Math.SE.  **Firstly**, it would help if you show what you have already tried. This helps us know where you got stuck, and allows us to better answer your question. **Secondly**, we use $\LaTeX$ to format math on this site.  I've edited the question to incorporate this--take a look, and try to use this for future questions; using $\LaTeX$ increases the chances that you get high-quality answers.  For help with $\LaTeX$, see [this meta question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What are you allowed to use?  There are library routines.  Presumably you are expected to worry about loss of significance in the subtraction.  What range of $x$ is that a worry?

Answer (score 6):

The meaning of the expression "write a function" is highly context-dependent. Do we need to implement $t^{1/3}$? We will assume that it is available.

In that case, the only issue that arises is for large $x$, where taking the difference between two nearly equal large numbers can lead to serious loss of accuracy.

There is a standard trick to deal with that, based on the identity $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$.

Set $a=(x+1)^{1/3}$ and $b=x^{1/3}$. Then $a^3-b^3=1$. It follows that 
$$(x+1)^{1/3}-x^{1/3}=a-b=\frac{1}{a^2+ab+b^2}.$$
The expression $\dfrac{1}{a^2+ab+b^2}$ can be safely handled by standard routines with minimal loss of precision due to truncation.

Comment: You are welcome. The most common issue is catastrophic loss of precision due to subtracting nearly equal quantities. The issue comes up many places, such as solving linear systems by row elimination. A great deal of work has been done to improve numerical algorithms to preserve accuracy. The little trick used above, and its relatives, are one example.